# How to plot an iGraph object on matplotlib axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, igraph

I have an iGraph object and I want to plot it on a Matplotlib axis,

the code for my graph is

```
from igraph import Graph, Layout
import igraph as ig
karate = Graph.Famous("Zachary")
layout = karate.layout_kamada_kawai()
visual_style={"bbox": (300, 300), "margin": 15, "layout": layout}

cl = karate.community_fastgreedy()
membership = cl.as_clustering().membership
pal = ig.drawing.colors.ClusterColoringPalette(len(membership))
karate.vs["color"] = pal.get_many(cl.as_clustering().membership)
karate.vs["size"] = 15
```

the iGraph documentation says that you can plot inside a Matplotlib axis using,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ig.plot(g, target=ax)
```

source : https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/visualisation.html

however, when I run,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ig.plot(karate, **visual_style, target=ax)
```

I get the following error,

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not AxesSubplot

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the pip version of python-igraph is 0.8.3. The documentation you're referring to is the master branch. You can look at the file [here](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/0.8.3/src/igraph/drawing/__init__.py) and note that matplotlib is not anywhere in the code, but if you look at the master branch [here](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/master/src/igraph/drawing/__init__.py) the implementation exists. If you want that functionality, then you can build from source, or wait for the next release.

Comment: Does this mean that I can use the master branch or not? Apologies if I mixed up references but can the documentation linked shows that it can be done and I think II have followed the steps correctly?

Comment: If you compile it from source you can, but if you're just using the pip installation you need to wait until the version on pip is updated with the most recent version of igraph.